# When to autogenerate installers with Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

We are setting up our first jenkins project. It's for a legacy Java project.
Is it a good practice to autogenerate an installer everytime a new commit is done?

We have a few developers, however I'm not sure if we should be autogenerating and archiving a .exe installer on every commit where jenkins succeeds to compile the code.

What other alternatives or good practices are used to decide when to autogenerate an installer and archive it?

Our concern is that we could start archiving autogenerated installers of versions with bugs or other problems if we auto generate on every commit, even if the compiling stage doesn't fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins should support your process, if you plan on delivering/pushing to production after every passing build it makes sense to generate the installers. If the build doesn't pass the installer won't get created.

I would however suggest you are are probably going to have fewer release to production, then you are commit to your SCM, so what I would do is I would have two jobs in Jenkins, the automated build per commit, and then a manual job (or perhaps scheduled) that will generate an installer for either the last successful builder, or the last build you have promoted to a release candidate.

There are a number of books and blogs on CI out there, but for me CI should support the process that is right for your team, not impose one on you.  Perhaps a good start is to get automated building going, and see how you want your process to grow form there.

Comment: Gavin, I like your ideas. Thanks. However, I would like to have it as automatic as possible. Can I do a 2nd job that automatically builds the last successful commit BUT only one time?  Another question, how does the "promoted to a release candidate" thing work? Thanks a lot

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson its been a long while since I have configured a CI on Jenkins, but from memory you were able to mark a build with a "marker" a coloured star if memory serves, you could then use this in another build to say, "builds with gold star".  You could set a build job to build your installer from the last successful commit every three months.  I am not sure if you can set to every x build.  Also check out TeamCity and GoCD, they might offer different options.